# PerformanceWarning when adding months to datetime values in Pandas DataFrame using apply() and DateOffset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a **"date"** column containing datetime values, and a **"months"** column containing integer values representing the number of months to add to each date. I want to calculate a new date for each row that is the original "date" plus the specified number of months in the months column.

I'm using the following code:

```
df['date'] + df["months"].apply(lambda y: pd.DateOffset(months=y))
```

This code seems to work correctly, but I'm getting a **PerformanceWarning** that says:

```
PerformanceWarning: Adding/subtracting object-dtype array to DatetimeArray not vectorized
  warnings.warn
```

I need to do this process with multiple date and months columns in my dataset and is taking a long time to perform this task.

Sample of input:

|  | date | months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-06-15 | 6 |
| 2 | 2022-02-28 | 1 |

Sample of ouput:

|  | date | months | new_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020-01-01 | 3 | 2020-04-01 |
| 1 | 2021-06-15 | 6 | 2021-12-15 |
| 2 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 2022-03-28 |

What does this warning mean, and how can I improve my code to avoid it? I'm concerned that this may be affecting the performance of my code, and I want to make sure that it's as efficient as possible.

Comment: Maybe you can try `df['new_date'] = df.apply(lambda y: y['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months=y['months']), axis=1)` ?

Comment: It tried it, it does not get the **PerformanceWarning** but it is taking twice as long to execute than the original one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the performance warning by using `.dt.date` on the date column.

For faster performance you can use `dateutil.relativedelta`:

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df['new_date'] = df['date'].dt.date + df["months"].apply(lambda y: relativedelta(months=y))
print(df)
```

Prints (without performance warning):

```
        date  months    new_date
0 2020-01-01       3  2020-04-01
1 2021-06-15       6  2021-12-15
2 2022-02-28       1  2022-03-28
```

---

Quick benchmark:

```py
from timeit import timeit
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def fn1(df):
    return df['date'].dt.date + df["months"].apply(lambda y: pd.DateOffset(months=y))

def fn2(df):
    return df['date'].dt.date + df["months"].apply(lambda y: relativedelta(months=y))

# create bigger dataframe
df = pd.concat([df]*100).reset_index(drop=True)

t1 = timeit('fn1(x)', setup='x = df.copy()', number=100, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit('fn2(x)', setup='x = df.copy()', number=100, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints:

```
0.6759202829562128
0.2161861159838736
```